# Why LD_PRELOAD doesn't work for one of loaded shared libraries?

Tags: c++, linux, apache2, shared-libraries, coredump

I have an in-house shared library on RedHat Linux 5.0 that provides functions `free` and `malloc`:

```
>nm ./libmem_consumption.so | grep -P -e "\bfree\b|\bmalloc\b"
0000000000006540 T free
00000000000088a0 T malloc
```

This shared library is responsible for providing information about memory consumption of a process.
Unfortunatelly there is a problem with this shared library when it is used with Apache `httpd`.
When Apache httpd is run with this library I get a coredump in `libc::free` and a message that the pointer is invalid.
The problem seems to be in http.so which is a shared library loaded by libphp5.so that is loaded by the `httpd`.

Actually when I do not load `http.so` everything is OK and there is no coredump.
(Loading or not loading `http.so` is managed by the directive in a configuration file: extension=http.so)
When I load `http.so` the httpd process coredumps.

`httpd` is lauched in this way:

```
LD_PRELOAD=./libmem_consumption.so ./bin/httpd -f config
```

and coredumps on exit.

When I set LD_BIND_NOW=1 and `http.so` is loaded I see (under gdb) that http.so has `free@plt` pointing to `libc::free` and in in other loaded 
libraries (for example `libphp5.so`) `free@plt` points to `libmem_consumption.so::free`.
How that could be possible?

By the way when I export LD_DEBUG=all and save output to a file I see these lines for libphp5.so (which is also loaded):

```
 25788: symbol=free;  lookup in file=/apache2/bin/httpd [0]
 25788: symbol=free;  lookup in file=/apache2/ps/lib/libmem_consumption.so [0]
 25788: binding file /apache2/modules/libphp5.so [0] to /apache2/ps/lib/libmem_consumption.so [0]: normal symbol `free' [GLIBC_2.2.5]
```

And completely different for http.so:

```
 25825: symbol=free;  lookup in file=/apache2/ext/http.so [0]
 25825: symbol=free;  lookup in file=/apache2/ps/lib/libz.so.1 [0]
 25825: symbol=free;  lookup in file=/apache2/ps/lib/libcurl.so.4 [0]
 25825: symbol=free;  lookup in file=/lib64/libc.so.6 [0]
 25825: binding file /apache2/ext/http.so [0] to /lib64/libc.so.6 [0]: normal symbol `free'
```

It seems that `LD_PRELOAD=./libmem_consumption.so` is not used for `http.so` when `free` is looked up. Why LD_PRELOAD is ignored?

Comment: Note that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46845496/ld-preload-and-linkage) I describe a case where `LD_PRELOAD` also doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seeems that http.so is loaded with the RTLD_DEEPBIND flag and that is why LD_PRELOAD is ignored for one of shared libraries.

This is from http://linux.die.net/man/3/dlopen:

> RTLD_DEEPBIND (since glibc 2.3.4)
>       Place the lookup scope of the symbols in this library ahead of the global scope. This means that a self-contained library will use its
>   own symbols in preference to global symbols with the same name
>   contained in libraries that have already been loaded. This flag is not
>   specified in POSIX.1-2001.

I wrote a test shared library:

```
  #include <dlfcn.h>
  #include <unistd.h>
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>
  #include <string.h>

  static void initialize_my_dlopen(void) __attribute__((constructor));

  void* (*real_dlopen)(const char *, int flag);
  static int unset_RTLD_DEEPBIND=0;
  static int _initialized = 0;

  static void initialize_my_dlopen(void)
  {
    if (_initialized)
        return;
    real_dlopen  = (void *(*)(const char *,int))dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "dlopen");
    unset_RTLD_DEEPBIND = atoi(getenv("UNSET_RTLD_DEEPBIND") ? getenv("UNSET_RTLD_DEEPBIND") : "0");
    printf("unset_RTLD_DEEPBIND: %d\n", unset_RTLD_DEEPBIND);
    _initialized = 1;
  }

  extern "C" {

    void *dlopen(const char *filename, int flag)
    {
      int new_flag = unset_RTLD_DEEPBIND == 0 ? flag : flag & (~RTLD_DEEPBIND);
      return (*real_dlopen)(filename, new_flag);
    }
  }
```

And built it:

```
  gcc -shared -fPIC -g -m64 my_dlopen.cpp -o libmy_dlopen.so -ldl
```

When I set UNSET_RTLD_DEEPBIND to 0 and run `httpd` the program coredumps.

```
export UNSET_RTLD_DEEPBIND=0
LD_PRELOAD=./libmy_dlopen.so:./ps/lib/libmem_consumption.so ./bin/httpd -f config
```

When I set UNSET_RTLD_DEEPBIND to 1 and run `httpd` everything is OK.

```
export UNSET_RTLD_DEEPBIND=1
LD_PRELOAD=./libmy_dlopen.so:./ps/lib/libmem_consumption.so ./bin/httpd -f config
```

And this is the output of LD_DEBUG=all for the UNSET_RTLD_DEEPBIND to 1:

```
 10678: symbol=free;  lookup in file=/apache2/bin/httpd [0]
 10678: symbol=free;  lookup in file=/apache2/libmy_dlopen.so [0]
 10678: symbol=free;  lookup in file=/apache2/ps/lib/libmem_consumption.so [0]
 10678: binding file /apache2/ext/http.so [0] to /apache2/ps/lib/libmem_consumption.so [0]: normal symbol `free'
```